# Reading lines from a file in c++17

Tags: c++, vector, file-io, c++17, std

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to transform from previous version of c++ to modern c++17.

I'm trying to read lines from a file. The contents are mostly gibberish and I'm doing this as an exercise to learn the language after not using c++ for many years.

The contents of the file I'm reading from are gibberish, i.e:
werweirwer
weriwrwjeie
werjiwrji

(after solving this I'll use it as an exercise to assign lines after filtering as input to constructors, use regex on it and basically develop it until I feel comfortable enough with input/out concepts, which may take some time).

However, it cannot read from the input file, even though it exists and in the same directory as the .cpp file (with reading permissions). IDE is clion if it matters.

Here's the code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
    
using namespace std;
    
std::vector<std::string> insertToVector(std::string k){
    std::vector<std::string> wordvector;
    if(k.empty()) {cerr<<"error reading from file: string is empty";}
    else {wordvector.push_back(k);}
    return wordvector;
}
    
int main() {
    fstream f("k.txt",ios_base::in);
    std::string templine;
  
    if(f){
        cout<<"Contents: \n";
        while(getline(f, templine)){
            cout<<"Contents:"<< templine; //just to output it simply
            std::vector<std::string> wordvector= insertToVector(templine);
            std::for_each(wordvector.begin(),wordvector.end(),[](const std::string word){std::cout<<word;}); //vector output
        }
    }else{
        std::cerr<<"couldn't open file";
    }
  
    f.close();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Additional question I wonder whether it is good to read lines with `while(getline())` or to use `while(!f.eof())` instead? Which is better in your opinion?

One more thing, I'm quite confused with functors and `std::function`, could you show me how to implement the `insertToVector` as `std::function` or functor and call it correctly?

Thank you very much. Doing my best to learn

EDIT: Fixed it using `auto path = fs::path`, and then using that reference with `fstream`. Worked well. Thank you very much for your explanations in the comments. Helped a lot in learning.

Comment: Your code reads the contents of input file correctly. Your problem probably is your IDE, which runs your compiled app within working directory different from where your sources are. You can either change open file path to `C:\path\to\the\k.txt` or put it in the right folder.

Comment: Your approach of checking the result of `getline()` is correct. Using `while (!in.eof())` is wrong: it doesn’t check whether the read attempt was successful and typically causes the last line to be used twice (if the last character in a file is a `’\n’` all characters are read but the end if file wasn’t touched; reading another character fails and gives an indication of what the error was by setting `std::ios_base::eofbit`). That’s not a matter of opinion. It is sad that correct input isn’t thought and people are copying the wrong code.

Comment: thank you very much for your comments and explanations, it really helps me learn more efficiently as i know what to avoid and why. i was wondering, what is the difference between the usage of getline versus using fstream getline on the object? i.e f.getline. are they interchangeable or the same?

Comment: [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) uses `std::string`, while [the other](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) char arrays. You can find the differences reading the references.